# Updating EmulationStation

Tags: emulation, update, retropie

Is it possible to update my version of EmulationStation on my Pi without uninstalling everything and installing a later version?

I'm using RetroPie v1.1 and I've installed a v2.3 (I think) on a previous Rasp Pi and it must of had a newer version of EmulationStation as the one that came with RetroPie v1.1 doesn't look too nice and has less features etc..

So basically I'm wondering if I can upgrade EmulationStation (fairly easily) from the Pi's command or do I need to start from scratch?

Answer (score 1):

unfortunately:

> Upgrading from RetroPie Version 1.X
>
> First of all, there is not
>   automatic upgrade function, if you would like to migrate your
>   configurations from a RetroPie version 1.X installation.
>
> That being said a migration is not too difficult...

continue reading here:

[source](http://blog.petrockblock.com/2014/07/01/major-update-for-retropie/)